# Transmissão de dados com Arduíno

Tags: c#, string, arduino, porta-serial

Estou monitorando 3 entradas analógicas de um *Arduíno UNO* e não sei se a forma que estou enviando dados para serial está correta, pois quando tento receber a informação em outra linguagem(*C#*) nem sempre vem no formato esperado.

```
int CANAL1, CANAL2, CANAL3, C1 = 0, C2 = 2, C3 = 5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
  CANAL1 = analogRead(C1);
  Serial.print(CANAL1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  CANAL2 = analogRead(C2);
  Serial.print(CANAL2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  CANAL3 = analogRead(C3);
  Serial.print(CANAL3);
  Serial.println();
  delay(10);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é melhor printar na serial dessa forma ou concatenar uma `String` e printar na serial. Ou alguma outra maneira onde eu não perca dados durante a transmissão dos mesmos.  Alguém para dar uma força?

> Na outra plataforma(*C#*) ao receber os dados e armazenar em uma String percebo que faltam dados na String enviada pelo Arduíno, e na grande maioria das vezes é no inicio da execução do programa que vem dados nulos.